# Communication between Native App and Chrome Custom Tab (CCT)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-extension, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

When I use Android `WebView` there are ways to communicate between web-app and native with `JS interface` call as well as `JS Injection` call. I wonder if there in any work around to communicate between Android native app and `Chrome Custom Tab (CCT)` by any mean?

I know for security reason Google does not added bridging feature in `CCT` and `TWA`. But in [Google I/O](https://youtu.be/6lHBw3F4cWs?t=563), they declared that there are limited ways of `Web/Native bridging` (refer the below figure). I wonder what are the ways as well as where can I find guidelines regarding these limited bridging?

[image]

### Update 1

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MyResultActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="abc"
            android:host="abc.oauth.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I am calling `abc://abc.oauth.com` in browser it does not open my activity. Its opening google search.

### Update 2

Finally I got the query params key/value with below code successfully,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Log.d(classTag, "MyResultActivity activity is called")

    intent?.data?.let {

        for (key in it.queryParameterNames) {
            val value = it.getQueryParameter(key)
            Log.d(classTag, "MyResultActivity param key: $key, value: $value")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot @Rahul for guiding me onwards.

Comment: If you want to do o-auth login or something similar then you need to register auth callback in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: How can I do so? that would be very helpful.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support extensions in Android so the tag ”google-chrome-extension” is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/do-authentication-in-android-using-custom-chrome-tab-cct-2a0edffc93fd) which show how to create it step by step.

1. Create a new request token
2. Get the user to authorize the request token
3. Create a new session id with the authorized request token

The main idea behind the whole thing is [Intent-Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) with category [browseable](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) which will get called whenever the redirect URL is called.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data 
   android:host="callback_param"
   android:scheme="anything"/>
```

Comment: Its not calling from CCT window with my, `scheme=https host=a-b.c.com/#/login/process`. Its opening the link in browser itself. Not opening my activity.

Comment: try to give it a custom `scheme` instead of `https`

Comment: when I try to browse the url, `https://a-b.c.com/#/#login/process` it actual page which is also exists in web app (valid URL). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Rahul, ok I will modify to custom scheme now. I will update you soon.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Also try to shorten your link and avoid using of `#`

Comment: ok I am using `abc://abc.oauth.com` this time. I have another question if I try the url in browser it should also open my activity right? Its not opening.

Comment: Rahul, I am getting the intent when I calling from CCT but how can I get authorization status which is in the parameters?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan in the `onNewIntent()` method see `intent.getAction()` and `intent.getDataString()` parameters

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan try to print values in Logcat for clear refrence

Comment: I managed to get params. `onNewIntent` never get called. I got in in `onCreate`. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan if you found your solution don't forget to accept the answer as well. As the original question was asked only about making a bridge between native and CCT.

Comment: Rahul, do you know how can I clear my app related data and cookies from CCT? When I log out from my app I cannot control cookie so in next login page it automatically logged in.

Comment: Also how can i close the CCT browser before starting new activity? I want to start my own webview when oAuth is done.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan you can send extra headers with the request but you cannot clear the cookies.